# Slow down processes in didReceiveMemoryWarning()

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

Is there anyway to slow down the processor when RAM reaches an x amount of memory or when `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` gets called?

```
func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning();
}
```

Comment: If there was, how would that help? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control CPU cores/resources from your application. Only the **Operating System** has control over it. Instead of looking to slow down CPU, optimise your code to use less memory, and discard any additional memory your app is using, in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method implementation.